# scala data analysis, doing group by by overlapping interval using pure scala

Tags: scala, data-analysis

I have a case class for storing data:
`case class A (x: String, y: String, a: Int, b: Int)`

Now the data is a List of case classes 
`List(A(x1, y1, a1, a2), A(x1, y2, a2, b2), ..., A(xn, yn, an, bn))` where A1, A2, A3 are different instance of case classes.

Now I need to group the data if the entries are in the overlapping interval defined by (a, b).

So if various records are like

```
List(
  A(x0, y1, 1, 5), 
  A(x0, y2, 3, 8), 
  A(x0, y3, 7, 10), 
  A(x0, y4, 12,15), 
  A(x1, y5, 1, 8), 
  A(x2, y6, 2, 7), ...)
```

the final grouping will be based on case class B:
`case class B (x: String, y:List(String), a:Int, b: Int)`

output: `List(B(x0, List(y1, y2, y3), 1, 10), B(x0, List(y4), 12, 15), B(x1, List(y5,y6), 1, 8), ...)`

Comment: What would be the key for group by, Is it x?

Comment: My mistake , it should be under x0

Answer (score 0):

This could be one possible solution, using Mutable Map.

```
case class A(x: String, y: String, a: Int, b: Int)
case class B(x: String, y: List[String], a: Int, b: Int)

val input = List(
  A("x0", "y1", 1, 5),
  A("x0", "y2", 3, 8),
  A("x0", "y3", 7, 10),
  A("x0", "y4", 12, 15),
  A("x1", "y5", 1, 8),
  A("x2", "y6", 2, 7))

val temp = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, B]()

input.map(data => {
  if (temp.contains(data.x)) {
    val _B = temp(data.x)
    val updatedList = _B.y ++ List(data.y)
    //TODO:
    //Range for a & b
    val a = data.a
    val b = data.b
    temp += (data.x -> B(data.x, updatedList, a, b))
  } else {
    temp += (data.x -> B(data.x, List(data.y), data.a, data.b))
  }
})
val output = temp.values.toList
println(output)
//List(B(x2,List(y6),2,7), B(x1,List(y5),1,8), B(x0,List(y1, y2, y3, y4),12,15))
```

Comment: oops, it is To do.